# Computer doesn't use more than 4 of my 8GB of RAM...? (64-bit computer)

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

Recently, to future-proof my computer, I've added on top of my original 4GB of memory. I brought the total memory to 8GB, and I've got no noticeable change in speed-- even when it should. I went to look into Task Manager and saw that my computer would NOT go over 4GB of memory being used, even with both Chrome and Firefox open with 20 tabs each.

After researching, everything that everyone had suggested to do was to check on how much memory was usable. Oddly enough, it says that I have 8GB of memory, and 7.74GB is usable.

[The specs for my HP Pavilion g7-1075dx can be found here.](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c02782018)
It is a notebook PC with Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit with AMD Phenom II.

My main question is: with my 64-bit computer, why is my computer not using more than 4GB of memory, even when more than 7 is usable?

EDIT: if it helps, Resource Monitor describes all the other RAM as "Standby"

Comment: How can you see that it is not using more than 4GB? Have you tried my other programs to test or use memory? Chrome and Firefox are not that demanding memory wise...

Comment: How precisely did you determine that it's not using more than 4GB? Be as specific as you can.

Comment: Nobody has, so far, mentioned that more RAM does *not* make a computer faster per se. The only time you'll see a noticeable speed bump is if your workload consumes so much RAM that Windows needs to continuously page to disk – in this case adding more RAM can definitely speed things up. But 98% of folks don't do the kinds of things that require >4GB RAM, and consequently, will never experience any tangible benefit in having all that extra RAM.

Comment: @misha256 When i said "future-proof," I was referring to the term of making your computer suitable for *gaming* in the future, not just for average use. Some of my games _do_ require a certain amount of RAM to even run (Contagion, Rust, etc.)

Comment: @mattycfp In that case why don't you run Contagion or Rust and check your RAM utilization with those? Why use Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: @mattycfp RAM you're not using is marked "Stand By". That's normal. You're not pushing Windows hard enough. How about you do a proper test. Launch Firefox AND Chrome and open a few tabs of YouTube videos in both. At the same time, run your most RAM-hungry game. If you *can* run more than one game at the same time, do so. THEN check your RAM usage, and let us know how you go.

Comment: @misha256 I did that. Both of them at the same time. Still only at 4GB.

Comment: @mattycfp There is one other possibility I know of that can limit Windows RAM usage. Is it possible that you, someone else, or some software put a LIMIT on RAM usage? Have a look at this article and follow the instructions: http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/fix-the-maximum-amount-of-memory-usable-by-windows-7-64-bit/

Comment: @Mokubai YMMV, but Firefox is usually the top consumer of memory in my environment (and in the case of Windows the top contributor to user profile size)

Comment: Are Chrome and Firefox 64-bit apps yet? I thought they were still 32-bit. Which means each can only individually use up to 4GB.

Comment: @fluffy They use multiple processes, so it doesn't really matter - the only hard limit would be 4 GiB per tab, not the whole browser. Even Facebook gets nowhere close to that, even being the huge memory hog it is :)

Comment: Firefox has a 2GB limit across all tabs/processes, chrome might too.  This is in addition to the normal per process limit.

Comment: Having Firefox and Chrome open with 20 tabs each is definitly not enough. I have Firefox open with 157 tabs it is not even consuming 1 GB of RAM. Check while runing the games. The answer of Jamie Hanrahan is very good and detailed. For further information read on Mark Russinovich's blog post Pushing the limits of Windows. [link](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/07/21/3092070.aspx).

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916959/can-a-32-bit-program-use-more-than-4gb-of-memory-on-a-64-bit-os

Comment: @sbecker If you've had 157 tabs open in Firefox between shutdowns and "continued where you left off" then Firefox does not seem to load all the tabs when it starts up. The tabs are only loaded as you navigate to them - saving time and memory. Chrome, however, seems to load the lot! I currently have 202 tabs open (help!) and it's consuming about 9GB. Incidentally, I also seem to be running 32-bit Chrome, however, I assume because of the "multi-process" nature of Chrome it is able to consume more than the standard 4GB. (?)

Comment: Have you bothered to Check `Control Panel --> System`? Have a look at the OS Version.  HP and other OEM's, aka Dell are notorious for putting 32-bit OS versions on 64 bit systems.  BTW, the memory limit of a 32-bit OS is 4GB.

Comment: If you want a program that simply uses tons of RAM you can just write one line of python (or other scripting language). E.g.: `a  = list(range(500000000));input()`. this will simply consume memory and wait for an enter. Increase the number at pleasure to use more memory.

Comment: @eyoung100 - "BTW, the memory limit of a 32-bit OS is 4GB..." when dealing with Microsoft Windows of course.

Comment: @w3d You're right. Haven't had all tabs loaded. Now at 187 tabs (all loaded) it gone up to 2GB. Chrome creates a new process for each tab. This is much more memory consuming but better performing. 9GB still sounds a bit much though.

Comment: If your machine is build to only address 4GiB (like mine is), you are out of luck.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> if it helps, Resource Monitor describes all the other RAM as "Standby"

"Standby" RAM *is* in use. It's being used as a page cache (it holds pages recently lost from all process working sets; i.e. page faults to these can be resolved without going to disk) and also for proactive file cacheing by SuperFetch.

It's considered "available" because Standby pages don't have to be written to disk before they can be assigned to some other use. Such as when a process hits a page fault that *does* require reading from disk, new physical page(s) must be allocated to that process, and if necessary these can be taken from the Standby list. (This is not the first choice for finding pages for this purpose, that would be the free and then the zero page list.)

In other words your system is operating as it should be.

You can force your system to get more RAM into the "in use" state easily with the command-line tool `testlimit`, one of the tools used in the experiments in *Windows Internals*. It is not part of the regular sysinternals tools but is associated with them; find it [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963901?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) at the sysinternals site. The download is a zip file that contains two versions, testlimit.exe and testlimit64.exe. Both are linked large-address-aware, so the 32-bit version will be able to allocate up to 3 GiB on a 32-bit machine booted with /3GB, up to 4 GiB on a 64-bit machine.

`c:\> testlimit -?` gives help.

`c:\> testlimit -d 4 -c 512` will attempt to allocate 2 GiB of process-private virtual address space in 512 allocations of 4 MiB each. This should work fine on a 64-bit machine. On a 32-bit machine *not* booted with /3GB (most are not) it may error a little earlier b/c there's already a few MiB of stuff in the process (like the program itself, all the DLLs, etc.), so there is not quite a full 2 GiB available for the program to allocate.

In both cases there will be a reduction in "available" RAM, and an increase in "In use" RAM, *but not necessarily 2 GiB worth* because there is no guarantee that the OS will leave all 2 GiB in the process private working set. Even if it does that in the short term, you may see the process working set decrease later as the OS decides "hm, you're not really doing anything with it, other processes need it more" and pages it out.

Increase the size of the allocation "chunks"  too much, reducing the number of chunks accordingly, and it will likely fail sooner as each allocation has to be virtually contiguous. e.g. try to find seven 512 MiB chunks in a 4 GiB address space and you'll likely fail.

If you use the l(eak) option instead of d(irty) the program will allocate the virtual space but will never reference it. This will *not* result in any appreciable decrease in "available" RAM.

(The d(irty) option takes its name from the "dirty page bit" in the x86/x64 page table entry, which is set when the corresponding virtual page is accessed with a "modify"-style operand, meaning the page's contents have been changed. This is Windows' indication that, should the page have to be evicted from the process working set, its contents have to be saved somewhere before the page can be used for something else. Pages with the "dirty" bit set go to the "modified page list" immediately after eviction; from there, Windows writes them to their respective backing stores.)

You will need to have sufficient "commit" available for these tests to work as described above (even for the l(eak) option, even though this option does not use any appreciable amount of RAM). Specifically, your "commit limit" should be at least 2 GiB (or however much you're allocating) higher than the "commit charge" before starting your test. Notice that this applies even if you're using the l(eak) option, not just d(irty). If you run into this limit you will see the "system is running low on memory" pop-ups or similar. The cure, of course, is to add more RAM and/or increase your pagefile settings.

Answer (score 15):

Windows can actually be configured to limit RAM usage. I don't know how or who would have configured this setting on your laptop, but you should check:

[image: Max Ram Setting]

This [article](http://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-7/fix-the-maximum-amount-of-memory-usable-by-windows-7-64-bit/) has more details, but getting to the above dialog box is easy:

1. Click the Start Icon and type `msconfig.exe` into the search box

   [image: how to launch msconfig]
2. Launch msconfig.exe, click on the `Boot` tab, then click the `Advanced Options...` button, and you're in:

   [image: msconfig boot settings dialog]
3. Either enter a sensible value, e.g. 8192 for 8GB RAM, *or* uncheck the `Maximum memory` checkbox entirely which should make Windows use all the RAM you have. I'd definitely try BOTH options.

   [image: maximum ram setting]

Comment: @misha256 - Deeply confused by an answer that had very little content originally, and yes, if somebody else submitted one of the answers I wouldn't have even thought twice about the answers ( except perhaps judge the helpfulness of them slightly harsher ).

Comment: @misha256 if this was the issue then OP wouldn't be seeing about 4 GB in use and about another 4 GB standby. The RAM that is excluded by that option doesn't show up in "standby"; OP also would not be seeing "8GB of memory, and 7.74GB is usable". (the 256 MB not "usable" is expected due to e.g. the video card).

Answer (score 10):

You can use [SysInternals RAMMap](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700229.aspx) to see exactly what the PC does with your *physical* RAM. Other tools like Task Manager or Process Explorer mainly focus on *virtual* memory and are not the best tools for this situation.

In the "Use count" tab, you may see that large portions are unused while you have not opened many applications.

[image: SysInternals RAMMap]

This does not mean your PC will ever remain in this state. Just open a few programs and the memory will get used.

Comment: The term "virtual RAM" should not be used. Also, I wouldn't say that those other tools focus mainly on virtual memory - they have plenty of counters available that show physical memory usage.

Answer (score 5):

Windows does some clever stuff such as paging memory. It could be that it sees most of the tasks you are doing as unnecessary and decides to dump a load of stuff into the page file, making it look like it's doing it just to avoid using up all your RAM. You could test this theory by disabling paging, although this is not a thing you should have permanently configured. There are many tutorials on the internet to do this. One of the things it does (even on my 24GB and 64GB machines) is to make the paging rules much more strict when it reaches approx 50%, 80%, and 90% consumption (these figures are approximate). I've noticed at each of these stages a load of stuff gets dumped into the page file.

A fun thing to do might be something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PAGE_SZ (1<<12)

int main() {
    int i;
    int gb = 2; // memory to consume in GB

    for (i = 0; i < ((unsigned long)gb<<30)/PAGE_SZ ; ++i) {
        void *m = malloc(PAGE_SZ);
        if (!m)
            break;
        memset(m, 0, 1);
    }
    printf("allocated %lu MB\n", ((unsigned long)i*PAGE_SZ)>>20);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

That's some C code. Get GCC or some compiler, make yourself an exe, and watch your memory consumption go up. If you want to consume more than 2GB of memory, you'll need to compile and run as a 64-bit process. If you're into that sort of thing it could be an interesting experiment, if nothing else :)

Edit: Just wanted to note that the program won't die with this. I edited it from some previous code since I'm not sure that other code would have worked (the memory would be paged, resulting in no memory being consumed, lol). The new code contains a line `int gb = 2; // memory to consume in GB` - changing the 2 will adjust the amount of memory the program should consume, thus you can set it to use up as much as you want. Setting it to something above what your system has will probably cause it to crash (not tested, so use with caution)

Comment: I wish I could compile it, but my Internet keeps corrupting every download I try :U

Comment: @mattycfp So you can't use >4GB of RAM in your OS, and all your downloads keep corrupting? Time to **(a)** WIPE the hard drive and do a fresh OS install, or **(b)** throw the laptop in the bin and get a proper one already.

Comment: The program offered allocates and "touches" 2 GB of virtual memory, one page at a time, which  will result in each page being faulted into RAM immediately after it's allocated. But that doesn't guarantee that Windows will keep it all in RAM at the same time. Since the program is not repeatedly accessing all of the v.m., the pages allocated first may be subject to being paged out. 

You can get the same effect as that program with the Windows Internals tool "testlimit", option -d .

Comment: @mattycfp if that's the case, you might want to see that the RAM is not at fault... Does every file you download get corrupted somehow? There are also sometimes issues with incompatible sticks, so you should check the motherboard manual and confirm that your RAM is organised according to those instructions (slots will be numbered either 1 & 2 or 1-4, and usually 1&3 must be paired up with the same "type" or "make and model" of RAM, as will 2 and 4).

& Yes this program should use up 2GB, that can be edited by changing the line `int gb = 2; // memory to consume in GB` - just change the 2.

Comment: Why did you declare gb to be of type int when the only use casts it to unsigned long?  You're also treating i the same way *and* doing a mixed comparison between the int and the cast-to unsigned.  So just make i unsigned long, also.

Comment: This code will not work on a 32-bit process (without tweaking things a bit) as those are limited to 2GB (31 bits) of virtual RAM in user space (the top half is kernel space) and after mapping in the program code, stack, heap, libc, etc. there will not be 2GB of memory available. If you intend it to be a 64-bit process, I recommend making the variable type `long long` (or `unsigned long long`) because Microsoft's compiler *always* treats solitary `long` as 32-bit. Also, why are you calling `memset`? Use `calloc` or don't bother zeroing the memory at all.

Comment: It will run in a 32-bit process, it just won't allocate quite all of 2 GiB. Because it allocates a page at a time it will grab address space in 4KiB pieces from what's available, stopping when the process v.a.s. is full. I assume he's calling memset to "touch" each page, since unless that is done no physical pages will be allocated, only virtual ones. You're right that calloc would accomplish that as well. There's still no guarantee that it will all _stay_ in RAM, though, so the RAM used by the process may well be a lot less than the v.a.s. it allocates... that's virtual memory for you.

Comment: @XtrmJosh  _"changing the 2 will adjust the amount of memory the program should consume, ... Setting it to something above what your system has will probably cause it to crash"_ - No. One, as Bob said, it can't go beyond 2 GB unless you link it large-address-aware. Two, your "2 GB" (or whatever you change the "2" to) is _virtual_ memory. You can allocate far more virtual memory than you have RAM. That's the whole point.. well, part of the whole point of virtual memory. The system I'm typing on has about 2x as much v.a.s. allocated as it has RAM. It's running fine.

Comment: This code will indeed not work as expected on a 32-bit process, I'll add that to the post any minute. I'm using memset because I was in a rush when I had to change the code (previous wouldn't have worked at all without my crazy GCC configuration on my linux dev box). Although it's probably not appropriate, it does the job. Now, the user asked why his computer wouldn't use more than 4GB of RAM. Using this code, it will indeed show in resmon (as OP indicated) a further 2GB of RAM is used. This memory is virtual, but it does the job of demonstrating that the machine is capable of allocating it.

Comment: @XtrmJosh Well, terminology can be tricky, and circumstances can vary. Assuming the alloc of all 2GB works, it will not _necessarily_ cause 2GB to move from "available" to "in use" and stay there. Your code only touches each alloc'd page once, so Windows might say "oh, you're not interested in those older pages any more" and page them out, esp. if the system is short on available RAM. Worst case, it could even use the the same page of RAM over and over again, 512K times!  The system in the OQ doesn't appear to be short on RAM, but... circumstances do vary.

Comment: @XtrmJosh see the additions to my answer describing use of the `testlimit` tool from sysinternals.

Comment: Oh, and another thing: re _"You could test this theory by disabling paging, "_ - sorry but **you can't disable paging.** You can disable use of the pagefile, but paging to and from disk will still be happening, just not to the pagefile.

Answer (score 5):

Quoting from a [very good article](http://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-much-ram-does-your-pc-need-probably-less-than-you-think/) on the subject:

> More memory doesn’t actually increase [a computer's] processing speed. Only a faster CPU can do that.

And in my experience that's absolutely true, in general. Unless you're running many programs at the same time *and* those programs have significant RAM requirements, you will hardly see any real-world benefit in having more than 4GB RAM.

People don't seem to realize that 4GB is a hell of a lot of RAM. Making Windows use more than that takes effort. You're going to have to open lots of *different* apps and, in those apps, open up some large files. Throw in a few tabs of YouTube videos and you might just start to see >4GB utilisation.

Comment: If you knew me, you'd know I have a lot of programs up ;) I mean, right now, I have 10 windows up, all doing different things :P

Comment: @mattycfp I've just opened up 16 Windows on my 4GB machine, including Internet Explorer, Firefox, Word, Excel, Outlook, Skype, Visual Studio 2010 (a known RAM hog), Photoshop, Media Player, VLC, MPC-HC, plus some other random apps, and I'm switching between them doing stuff, loading documents, playing videos, everything, and my actual RAM usage is 2.2GB AND the machine is FAST as it ever was. See, 4GB does all that easy ;-)

Comment: And yet my current craptop has 8GB and can hardly run 120 different windows of FF.

Comment: @mattycfp 120 Windows of FF? You're more likely to max out your CPU than RAM doing that, especially on a laptop. Also don't forget FF is a 32-bit app, and multiple FF windows actually SHARE a single 32-bit process, so FF is actually quite limited, it can only use 2GB of your 8GB total. That's why you need to run lots of *different* apps at the same time to test how Windows uses your RAM, not just 120 Windows of FF.

Comment: @misha256 You *will* see performance gains if your system is constantly swapping memory. As memory pressure increases, paging increases, and the system slows down. It's not that adding memory will make you go faster, but it *will* keep you from slowing down, especially if the software involved assumes a certain amount of paging in its system requirements. That article didn't seem to mention much about paging. Paging is what slows you down.

Comment: @misha256 I have IRC, Spotify, Notepad++, Chrome and Task Manager open and I'm using 3.02GB out of my total 4GB :( Opening up 3 VS2013 instances (which I tend to do at work) and that maxes me out. It's a bit easier to reach 4GB limit than you'd think, but practically requires a power user.

Comment: @misha256 Correction: FF is large-address-aware and can address up to 3GB in a 32-bit process. The 64-bit version of FF (currently in beta for Windows) can obviously address far more. I also feel you are generalising a bit too much when saying it's hard to "use" (resident private working set) more than 4GB of RAM; it really depends a lot on what you're doing and how much you keep open. My baseline usage already exceeds that.

Comment: I'm not so sure 4 GB is that much any more. According to Resource Monitor, I have 8063 MB in use and 4110 MB on Standby on my machine. I'm *multitasking*...i.e. running Outlook, OneNote, Word, Firefox, Remote Desktop Client, Excel, Calculator, Access, a financial program, Adobe Reader and two utilities.

Comment: @Bob Absolutely true re FF, I stand corrected. BUT, I have never been able to make FF use >2GB (on 64-bit OS) without it crashing. Might be a FF bug, or limitation of some component(s) it uses. I discovered this when I was trying to diagnose FF crashes with the Spotify web-player. That was a memory leak issue, but in all tests (using all sorts of different web sites) >2GB was impossible to achieve. Obviously we're talking about 32-bit FF here.

Comment: @misha256 That's because the 3GB refers to commit size, which is not the metric Task Manager displays by default. Due to various reasons, especially heap fragmentation, private working set can be much lower than commit. Then you need to factor in things like shared libraries and memory mapped files, that all use user address space.

Comment: @Bob "FF is large-address-aware and can address up to 3GB in a 32-bit process." Just to clarify: On a 32-bit system that requires the increaseuserva option in the BCD (/3GB in the old boot.ini). This does have some cost in that it squeezes the kernel code and data into just 1 GB. On an x64 system this feature is always available, no special boot option needed, and a large-address-aware process can address up to _4_ GB.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a 32-bit program to test how fast the computer is running?  If so, note that 32-bit addresses can only point to 4 GB of the RAM, even if you have more RAM present.  You'll need to repeat the test using a 64-bit program and checking its speed with 4 GB of RAM present, and again with 8 GB of RAM present, if you want useful results.  Also, it will need to be a 64-bit program which can use more than 4 GB of memory to run faster - not all of them can.  To tell if a program is 32-bits, start the program and leave it running, then start Windows Task Manager, click on Processes, and scroll down until you find the program of interest.  If the name of the program in the Image Name column is followed by a space, then *32, then it is a 32-bit program.

Comment: if you run several 32-bit programs, their total RAM use can easily reach 8 GB.

Answer (score 0):

Get [*process explorer* (procexp) from Sysinternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx).  It has a resource graph and can show per-process memory use, much better than the stock process view.

You can look at physical ram use vs virtual spqce usage, to see if you're simply not using it all up *or* you seem to need more but are limiting the physical usage.

Most mundane programs use a different *working set* size that will keep demand low. If a program allocates a ton of memory it's not really *using* all of it at the same time...

Windows will agressivly move pages from your program to a list where they are available, *but* if a page fault occurs it will be pulled back frommthe list without having to load it from the swapfile.  The *standby* might be including these.  Different tools label different sets in different ways.

You could try turning off the swap file, at least for this test. That will cause data memory to really be used. Though procexp might be enough to see that clearly.